# FullCalendar - Bold Title?

Tags: format, fullcalendar

Am I able to bold the titles of events in Full Calendar?

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
      theme:true
});

var title = "A Title";
var startDate = "new Date()";
var endDate = "2020-01-01 00:00:00";
var event = {
                title : title,
                allDay : true,
                start : moment(startDate),
                end : moment(endDate),
                backgroundColor : '#ffffff',
                textColor: '#000000',
            }
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',event);
```

How do I go about this? With Html or is there a built in way?

Comment: CSS may be the easiest/best route if you want all titles to be bolded. span.fc-title { font-weight: bold; } // I think should do it.

Comment: @smcd I was thinking it'd be nice to bold only certain sections of the title if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the eventRender callback function the first argument will help you. This example should bold the title. You can set all of callback functions in the initializer of the fullcalendar like this. Then just put the callback function in the same js file

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    theme:true,
    eventRender:eventRenderCallback,
});


function eventRenderCallback(event, element, view){
    var title = element.find(".fc-title").val();
    element.find(".fc-title").html("<b>"+title+"</b>");
}
```

Comment: You might want to print out the event object. I retrieve events differently and the title might be there for you.

Comment: I don't think I understand where to call this in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer and it should explain it more clearly

Answer (score 2):

It seems that i can't use Daffy answer.

What works for me is:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                    $(element).css("font-weight", "bold");
            },
        });
```